# WSO2 API Manager - Can not get lifecycle configurations of 'APILifeCycle' lifecycle

Tags: wso2-api-manager

While designing the WorldBank API using the WSO2 API Manager publisher UI in version 2.1.0, I get the following error when moving from creation to the Implement phase of publishing.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-27 14:36:21,534] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler} -  Lifecycle 'APILifeCycle'checkpoint addition failed for state Created {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Error while building OM element to lifecycle configurations of 'APILifeCycle' lifecycle.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.util.LifecycleStateDurationUtils.getLifecycleConfigurationElement(LifecycleStateDurationUtils.java:360)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.util.LifecycleStateDurationUtils.getDurationBeans(LifecycleStateDurationUtils.java:320)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.tasks.LCNotificationScheduler.addScheduler(LCNotificationScheduler.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.addLCNotificationScheduler(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:614)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.put(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:970)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:292)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:205)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:949)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.associateAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2474)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.associateAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:499)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspectInternal(UserRegistry.java:1901)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3800(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1873)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspect(UserRegistry.java:1870)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.attachLifecycle(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:383)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2335)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:610)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:1059)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_createAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:964)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_5(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:108)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_39(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:124)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:166)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:21)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Can not get lifecycle configurations of 'APILifeCycle' lifecycle.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.util.LifecycleStateDurationUtils.getLifecycleConfigurationElement(LifecycleStateDurationUtils.java:356)
    ... 103 more
```

The UI continues on to the next screen, which is step 2 Implement.  I am able to add the managed back end endpoint, set the manage config, then save/publish.

Is this exception something to be worried about?  It seemingly just started happening without any changes to configuration of my all-in-one instance.  I was able to publish, delete, publish, delete, publish etc the WorldBank service many times without this exception in wso2carbon.log.  It now happens every time I create a new API, be it the WorldBank sample or the PhoneVerify sample.

I have included a link to my api-manager.xml:
[api-manager.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw85-_8kJfHqTnZvV1d0ZUN4SGM)

I am using version 2.1.0 with MySQL databases configured per https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment and SAML2 federated login enabled to the store and publisher applications.  This happens whether or not I am logged in as admin or as my federated identity login.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether you have mounted target path to "/_system/config"  in registry.xml ?

Comment: I checked and I do have that set in the /_system/config mount path:

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
    </mount>

 Here is a link to my registry.xml:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw85-_8kJfHqck01RXQ5Y3JVMWM